# frontier internet - cant connect to google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hey guys having a problem with google cloud over Frontier internet. Stumped a bit, because everywhere else I've tried I am able to at least telnet to the SSH port. Internet sites to check port open all pass, and from Amazon EC2, Azure, and Work environments, and from cellphone network I am able to telnet to the port. However, over Frontier Internet here in Tampa I am not. Contacted Frontier and they basically said "not our problem after 14 hops".

```
 Tracing route to 225.189.186.35.bc.googleusercontent.com [35.186.189.225] 
 over a maximum of 30 hops:


  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CISCOWIRELESS [10.192.25.194]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  3     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  47.199.192.1
  4     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  172.99.47.198
  5     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  ae7---0.scr01.mias.fl.frontiernet.net [74.40.3.69]
 6    34 ms     7 ms     7 ms  ae0---0.cbr01.mias.fl.frontiernet.net [74.40.1.22]
 7     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  72.14.204.188
 8     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  209.85.240.177
 9    19 ms    20 ms    20 ms  74.125.37.48
10    50 ms    50 ms    50 ms  209.85.255.245
11    50 ms    50 ms    50 ms  216.239.48.100
12    50 ms    50 ms    50 ms  108.170.240.97
13    50 ms    50 ms    57 ms  108.170.238.183
14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: If you are able to connect to your VM using the SSH applet on https://console.cloud.google.com/ then you can run a traceroute in the other direction as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you're unable to get *any* traffic from Frontier's network to Google Compute's network, the issue lies with one of the two providers. Unfortunately there's very little you can do other than prod both until they help you out. It may be worth temporarily subscribing to a "real" support plan with Google to see if that will spur some action.

Comment: Not sure I understand, I can connect to other cloud's over SSH from this network. For example I can connect over SSH to amazon ec2 and azure compute instances. I have a hard time thinking Frontier blocked my port 22 specifically to google?

Comment: Hrm, can you get *any* traffic to the GCE instance? Temporarily remove all restrictive firewall rules.

Comment: yep i removed everything, 0.0.0.0/0 allow everything... and again, i can successfully connect outside of my Frontier connection.... Frontier said "not my problem"... so here I am... something is blocking the Frontier connection, Frontier said it was google... google pointed me here to stackoverflow/serverfault... again this PC i am typing on can connect to SSH on other cloud providers, however google, I get nothing. ill try HTTP port and see if its just SSH.

Comment: The question is: can you get *any* traffic to the instance from the Frontier connection? If not, then it *is* Frontier's problem to solve, even if it lies with one of their upstream providers.

Comment: Confirmed, I can't even hit http... http://35.186.189.225/index.html. I'll point Frontier at this I guess. This is stupid.

Comment: Frontier is telling me it's not them, its google. So looks like I need to cough up 150.00 for a month of support here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't hit that URL from Comcast right now. Have you tried assigning a different IP to your server? Do you have a dynamic IP with Frontier? If not, cycle your modem to see if you get a different IP.

Comment: @EAAA i brought down the server... it has to be either google or Frontier. in any case I moved the servers from east to central (regions) and i have no problems connecting from Frontier. so its specific to the east DC for google (tracert for east goes all the way to Palo Alto Networks in Texas... weird). Anyway... kicked the can down the road a bit.